# MySQL table design for overlapping

Tags: mysql

I have 50,000 unique cards in a table. A minimum of 2 cards and up to 20 cards can be chosen by the user and they can write a blurb about it. There will be times when the cards chosen by different users will overlap. When the exact same cards are chosen, I'd like to store the new blurb but keep the table clean as possible by not storing overlaps as many people may choose the same 2 cards but write different blurbs. How should I design my table to prevent overlap of information?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want to learn.

Comment: Just let them overlap. There's no problem here, so no answer to provide!

Comment: I don't want them to overlap because I'll be frequently querying them later. Please don't respond if you don't have the skill to answer my question.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I'm being dim but I cant see the problem here.

Comment: The goal is to make a table where the card choices never overlap.

Comment: Users can select from  between 1 and 20 values. So there are 20 factorial possible combinations. This is a 2 followed by 18 zeros (roughly). I just cannot see why you would want to store the combinations that had already occurred. What problem does storing them solve?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I don't want just the combinations that already occurred. I'd like to store all combinations that users chose but no duplicate rows with the same choices. So if user B picks the same cards as user A, I'd like to save the blurb and which user it was written by but not have the duplicate selection exist in the table.

Comment: There's going to be a lot of cards that have preference over others so the numbers will be a lot smaller. I guess I should clarify, I've already solved the problem but I want to see if anyone comes up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: If it was me, for ease of comprehension, I'd simplify the problem. Let's say a user can choose between 2 and 5 cards from a list of of 10. Now, what might the CREATE and INSERT statements for that look like, and what kinds of queries might we enact upon it?